# How selecting parent element from iframe.contents()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I wanted to call a function, when I click in an iframe, and my solution works pretty fine with jQuery, but I need to get back to the element containing the iframe, when the function is triggered.

```
$('#window-3 iframe').load(function () {
  $(this).contents().find("body").click(function () {
    // Here I need to select the iframe again
  });
});
```

Comment: What is wrong with just using the `$('#window-3 iframe')` or make a reference like in the answers below?

Comment: I'm guessing he has more than one iframe in there and possibly has multiple `#window-*`s

Comment: That's right, I'm using multiple iframes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to you `$(this).parent()` in this case. If you want to select a parent with a specific class you can use `$(this).parents('#window-3')` for example.

You may also want to clear up any potential scoping issues:

```
$('#window-3 iframe').load(function () {
  var _me = $(this);

  _me.contents().find("body").click(function () {
    var _parent = _me.parent()
    // Here I need to select the iframe again
  });
});
```

Comment: Not sure why my post received a downvote immediately after it was posted?

Comment: Very usefull, thank you. Didn't thought about defining another variable before creating the function, which would take over that one. Maybe the one downvoting you was just about to write the same :)